# workflow passing out values between activities

Tags: c#, .net, workflow, workflow-foundation-4

I have a CodeActivity GetEstimatedArrivalTime that gets a datetime and returns it as an out argument.

In the designer view, how can I take this value input it into the sequence diagram?

```
public sealed class CodeActivityGetEVA : CodeActivity
{
    public InArgument<int> EventID { get; set; }
    public OutArgument<DateTime> EVA {get;set;}

    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {
        EVA.Set(context, DateTime.Now);
    }
```

Comment: use property binding

Comment: I tried googling that a little and not alot of ideas.

Comment: not sure about new version, old version have a yellow can near the TARGET property, clicking on it allow you to bind with some other property. If no yellow can , property is not bindable. But remember I'm talking about the old interface

Comment: old being 3.5 or 4 or 4.5?

Comment: 3.5 then I just quit to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize a variable at sequence level (lets call it "EstimatedArrivalTimeVar") and attach it to `CodeActivityGetEVA`'s `EVA` out argument. From then on you can use `EstimatedArrivalTimeVar` with the value assigned to it.

Note that you can use a CodeActivity with a *TResult* as an out argument already available:

```
public sealed class CodeActivityGetEVA : CodeActivity<DateTime>
{
    public InArgument<int> EventID { get; set; }

    protected override DateTime Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {
        return DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```